# Help on Vinyl floors

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I had a new vinyl floor put around 8 months ago. There is a square in the middle where it has damaged the floor. It is in the middle of the kitchen floor. Is there anything I can do to make this look better without having to replace the whole floor?

Comment: Are they vinyl tiles?

Comment: "There is a square in the middle where it has damaged the floor" is unclear. **What** has damaged the floor?

Comment: A photo might help people advise what can / can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

If, by "a square" you mean that you have rigid vinyl tile flooring (that typically comes in 12"x12" squares) you can pull up and replace a single tile (or have that done, depending on your preference.)

If you have sheet-type vinyl flooring where one piece covers the whole floor, you either need to accept some new seams or replace the whole thing.

Or put a rug over the damaged area ;-)